# saving spritebatch texture so i can use it in other methods later on

Tags: libgdx

I’m new to libgdx and I'm trying to create a simple dots and boxes game. I have sat up the board and drawline method using batch.draw()

```
batch.draw(lineH, Xpoints[2]+16, Ypoints[2], (screenW-16), lineH.getHeight());
```

of course that’s according to where the user clicks

"if that’s oh any help each dot has to lines coming out of it(one is horizontal and the other is vertical)"

now I want to find a way to store the drawn lines so the player clicks the same line it tells him that its an illegal move. also I want to use that later to calculate the scores. So how can I do that?!

Comment: I have not the slightest clue what you want to know... spritebatch? lines? illegal move? scores? dots and boxes game?! WTH

Comment: lol dots and boxes game "http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Games/dots&boxes.html" here is about the game.. i tried posting some pictures but i couldn't

Comment: anyways i found a way to do that i stored rectangles with the same size of the spriteBatch in an array list and added a loop to go thro it and check for if the input is contained within the rectangle 
if(rect.contains(clickX, clickY))
that would be an illegal move coz ur not allowed to play the same line twice

Comment: @Jay Taylor have you read any basic libgdx tutorials? "i stored rectangles with the same size ofthe spriteBatch"- this sounds a bit strange. Take a look at this great tutorials: http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/ and http://steigert.blogspot.it/2012/02/1-libgdx-tutorial-introduction.html